# Will AJAX methods calls complete when an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, exception

When a menu item is clicked in my menu an ASCX control is loaded via AJAX in my asp panel. To do this I have a method:

```
public void LoadControl(ControlDestination controlDestination, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        // Load control from file
        Control control = LoadControl(filename);

        // Check control extends BaseForm
          // Do stuff    
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Web User Control erft niet van BaseForm.");
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        // Implement
    }
    catch(HttpException e)
    {
        LoadControl(ControlDestination.Menu, "Error.ascx");
        throw new Exception("User control niet gevonden: " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the HttpException I get there. I press F11 and the code in LoadControl is executed. Then the excetpion pops up. All this goes well, but Error.ascx is never loaded. I know the method is working because when I want to load other ASCX objects via this method it works. But When I want to load Error.ascx is goes wrong.

I can see Error.ascx if I comment out throw new Exception("User control niet gevonden" + e.ToString()); I want both lines to be executed.

EDIT:

In my master page I have this javascript code to catch some exceptions:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    manager.add_endRequest(endRequest);
    manager.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
}

function endRequest(sender, args){
    var Error = args.get_error();
    if (Error != null) {
        ToggleErrorOn(true);
        document.getElementById("ErrorContent").innerHTML = Error.message;
        args.set_errorHandled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, if you throw an exception after loading your control, your entire page will be 'execptio-ed' unless you have catch that exception when calling "LoadControl" method.

Comment: What do you mean by, my whole page will be execptio-ed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger a server-side method in an `UpdatePanel` ASP.NET does the following:

1. Rebuilds the portion of the page
   within the panel from scratch by
   running through the normal ASP.NET
   page lifecycle (well, slightly
   abridged, but close).
2. Sends the panel's HTML back
   to the client.
3. Rebuilds the panel on the
   client using javascript DOM
   manipulation.

If there's an unhandled `Exception` during the first step, the AJAX call fails and it cannot update the originating panel. Here's a diagram [from the ASP.NET AJAX web site](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx):

[image: Partial-Page Rendering Overview]

Consider what would happen if you threw an unhandled `Exception` in `Page_Load`. ASP.NET wouldn't be able to finish constructing your HTML in that case, and it cannot do so here.

Comment: But when i am in the debugger and set a breakpoint in the exception, the code is executed. Why is that?

Comment: In my startpost I've added some javascript code which handles the exception

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by throwing the Exception after loading your error control?

Comment: Thnx for the explanation. When an exception occurs I want 2 things: 1.call a method (that will take care of some UI things) and 2. pass the error to the client. I show the error in a overlaying div. I also want the error to be written in the database.

Comment: Got it! You can accomplish both of those things inside your HttpException handler after calling LoadControl, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Okay.. so after I've called LoadControl() then I do stuff in the DB and then the tricky part.. show the error in the div. How am i going to do this?

Comment: It's probably easiest to create your overlay error div directly in your .aspx with runat='server' so that you can access it in your code-behind as an HtmlGenericControl and specify visible='false' so that it doesn't normally render. Then, in your error handler set its Visible property to true.

Answer (score 0):

An uncaught exception causes the Update Panel to fail any rendering.  Instead, it relays an error code back to the AJAX handler which displays the error message.

As such, if you keep throwing that exception, your Error.ascx will never get rendered.

UPDATE:

Your javascript catches the exception too late.  The UpdatePanel pipeline has already considered itself in the "errored" state.  Any exception thrown **by your codebehind** but not caught **in your codebehind** will cause UpdatePanel to drop all HTML it would have rendered and return a simple error code.  Which your javascript function is then handling.

Comment: I've added catch(Exception e){LoadControl(ControlDestination.Menu, "Error.ascx");
        throw new Exception("User control niet gevonden: " + e.ToString());
} But I still get the same error and my error.ascx ain't loaded

Comment: The Exception that *you* are throwing is uncaught, and it terminates the AJAX operation.

Comment: In my startpost I've added some javascript code which handles the exception

Comment: Javascript cannot "handle" errors thrown by your codebehind.  You'll have to catch it in the codebehind or else the UpdatePanel will abort itself.